# Websocket connection by Apache2 + mod_wsgi + Django

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I am deploying a django project on apache2 using mod_wsgi.
I can confirm to see Django's page from apache2 server but websocket cannot connect, 
I think that Django-channels doesn't start by apache2.

So I solve this problem to install 'asgi_redis' to start Django-channels.

```
'pip3 instal asgi_redis'
```

I changed channel layer.

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
            "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
             },
            "ROUTING": "mysite.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

And I tried the follow command.

```
'python3 manage.py runworker'
```

But the following error occured.

```
2017-07-27 08:07:59,660 - INFO - runworker - Using single-threaded worker.
2017-07-27 08:07:59,661 - INFO - runworker - Running worker against channel 
layer default (asgi_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer)
2017-07-27 08:07:59,663 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels 
http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 494, in _connect
raise err
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 482, in _connect
sock.connect(socket_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 572, in execute_command
connection.send_command(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in send_command
self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 538, in send_packed_command
self.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. 
Connection refused.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
sock = self._connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 494,in _connect
raise err
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 482, 
in _connect
sock.connect(socket_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/channels/management/commands/runworker.py", line 83, in handle
worker.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/channels/worker.py", line 87, in run
channel, content = self.channel_layer.receive_many(channels, block=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/asgiref/base_layer.py", line 43, in receive_many
return self.receive(channels, block)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/asgi_redis/core.py", line 215, in receive
result = connection.blpop(list_names, timeout=self.blpop_timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 1163, in blpop
return self.execute_command('BLPOP', *keys)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 578, in execute_command
connection.send_command(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, 
in send_command
self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 538, 
in send_packed_command
self.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, 
in connect
raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

Need help in resolving this error.

Raspberry Pi 3
Ubuntu 16.04.2
Django 1.11.1
Apache2 2.4.18

Comment: You can't use web sockets over WSGI, which is what mod_wsgi implements.

Comment: My mod_wsgi version is '4.5.17.'

Comment: Know the mod_wsgi version doesn't change anything. You can't use web sockets through mod_wsgi in any way. WSGI servers that support web sockets rely on stepping outside of the WSGI specification and directly working with the raw socket connection from the client. That is not possible with mod_wsgi.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I don't get your comments. I did a working chat with Flask socket IO and it is served by my Apache server which use mod_wsgi : | are you telling us that Flask Socket IO is a non sens ?